# What template is called by <xsl:apply-templates /> with no select attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Learning XSLT and need to understand what template is called on line 8 via `<xsl:apply-templates />` see an example code below ↓ . `<xsl:apply-templates select="something"/>` makes more sense because of the `select` attribute meanwhile `<xsl:apply-templates />` has no attributes so it is hard to tell.

```
    <xsl:template match="content">
        <xsl:if test="set_0/col_0 != ''">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="set_0/col_0" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="col_1">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is short for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` meaning it applies templates to all child nodes of the context node. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#applying-templates which says

> The default value of the select attribute is child::node(), which
>   causes all the children of the context node to be processed.

Comment: Ok, so lets say I have `<xsl:template match="col_1">` which targets `<col_1>` elements in my .XML file, right? So inside  `<xsl:template match="col_1">` I have `<xsl:apply-templates />` → Does this simply mean that the template used for `<col_1>` will be also applied for all children of `<col_1>`?

Comment: It will apply only it's own children or decadents nodes.

Comment: Please read the linked document section or any tutorial on template based processing, the section clearly says "Each item in the input sequence is processed by finding a template rule whose pattern matches that item. If there is more than one such template rule, the best among them is chosen, using rules described in 6.4 Conflict Resolution for Template Rules. If there is no template rule whose pattern matches the item, a built-in template rule is used (see 6.7 Built-in Template Rules)." so the child nodes of your `col_1` elements will be processed by matching templates you write or built-ins.